# How to disable/stop (showLoginAlert) function from appearing?

Tags: swift

I have login alert connected to `UIViewController` called `Intro` the alert show up in home screen and in all `tabBar` views when the user click in one of them, the alert prevent user from using the app unless he sign up. I want to stop the alert from showing because I'm implementing it somewhere else.

I tried to delete/comment the code but that resulted in a lot of errors showing

```
// MARK: - SHOW LOGIN ALERT

func showLoginAlert(_ mess:String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: APP_NAME,
        message: mess,
        preferredStyle: .alert)

    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        let aVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Intro") as! Intro
        self.present(aVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
alert.addAction(ok)

let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in })
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


// MARK: - FIRE A SIMPLE ALERT

 func simpleAlert(_ mess:String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: APP_NAME,
        message: mess, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in })
    alert.addAction(ok)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: comment out the line where your are calling `showLoginAlert ` and `simpleAlert`

Comment: or just comment out `present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)` that would be simple and you can undo that easily if needed

Comment: @RaziTiwana  when commenting present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil nothing happens it still shows up and when trying it with showLoginAlert and simpleAlert i get around 16 error